# How to design mutually dependent models with callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, callback, rails-activerecord

So I have 2 models `A` and `B`.

When `A` is saved or destroyed, `B` needs to be updated based on what happened with `A`.

When `B` is saved or destroyed, `A` needs to be updated based on what happened with `B`.

I can't just put 2 callbacks, it will lead to models having callbacks recursively. I don't need the callback to fire when model `A` is saved as result of firing `B` callback and vice versa.

What is the rails way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation, the best thing you can do is using a flag in your callbacks

```
class A
  attr_accessor :is_updated_by_callback
  after_commit :update_b

  def update_b
    return if is_updated_by_callback
    b.is_updated_by_callback = true
    b.update
  end 
end
```

and vice-versa

Comment: Ugly? I don't know what that mean. Perhaps with the proliferation of frameworks in the past 15 years we tent to forget about flags but it's often useful. Have a little fun and search your gems source for "flag", you may be surprised. Anyhow if you find a better solution you will be kind to let me know.

Comment: For instance, to do things properly I will have to reset the flag in the callback that reads it, and if there are more than one consumer callbacks - it gets complicated. I agree that flag is a pretty ordinary thing.

Comment: You do not have to reset the flag, because it is not saved in database, thanks to `attr_accessor`. And if you have more than one callback that may be trigger at once then you can use bitwise flag instead of boolean

Comment: If I would want to reuse model instance (agree that this is a rare case, and maybe a bad design desision) - I have to reset, because I can get unwanted callback skip otherwise.

Comment: I see. Then indeed you need a more complex design of your callbacks, because Rails has not been designed for this kind of situations as you can see in activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#run_callbacks. Perhaps you could use `Kernel.caller` to verify that the action is triggered by a callback - but that kind of technique enters in my definition of `ugly` because we rely on rails internals that may change in the future

Answer (score 1):

You can use `update_columns` in your callbacks:

e.g:

model A was saved. In the callback, you have something like this:

```
recordB.update_columns(:name => '')
```

update_column will not run any callback.
note: It will also not run validation, or update the updated_at field.

Comment: Will work, right, unless i need validation and other, unrelated callbacks to work. So there is no better way, i guess..